# Positioning pseudo elements without absolute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to position a CSS pseudo element vertically to the top of the div element it is attached too. Here is the code:

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
     text
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
   padding: 20px;
}

.content {
   padding: 10px;
}

.content::after {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

The caveats are that I cannot use position: absolute or a negative margin on the pseudo element. The content divs are being dynamically inserted into the container div which is using flex-box and therefore position absolute doesn't work. The content div's also vary in height and therefore a negative margin-top cannot be used.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DonnieDarko1/4jcvtc65/).

Comment: Can you use `position: relative`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/In_Flow_and_Out_of_Flow#taking_an_item_out_of_flow), and use the pseudo `:before` instead, you take it out of flow before the text, and in combo with `transform: translate`, you can achieve this.

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content:before {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  float: right;                  /* out of flow, position right of text */
  transform: translateY(-20px);  /* match padding value */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    text text text<br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Updated***

I also need to say that `display: flex` won't be a problem either, whether is is set on the `container`, `content` or both.

Flex children respect positioning when set, and if `display: flex` is only set on the `container`, the pseudo element isn't even a flex item.

*And with this you can also use the `after` pseudo if needed, as in some situations, if there's a need to use `nth-*` or similar, it might be easier to use which one works best.*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container > * {
  position: relative;            /* give first child position */
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;            /* absolute position */
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  right: 20px;                   /* match padding value */
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    text text text<br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
    text text text<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is the outcome I am looking for however I'm unable to use top: -10px as the content divs vary in height. top: -10px works for a content div of this height but not one double its height.

Comment: @Donnie There is no -10px ... please refresh the page

Comment: Good answer, just wanted to say that `top: 50%;` doesn't have any effect, it is ignored since the before-element doesn't have any particular `position` set it'll be `position:static` and thus `top` has zero effect.

Comment: I think you can skip `top:50%`. I'm also not sure if `float:right` is necessary. Maybe you can just transform both x and y via `transform: translate()`

Comment: @Drkawashima ...They all work together, and all needed in this setup. If you change the height of the "red box" (it now matches the parents padding, hence you won't see the difference), and then disable each of those 3 properties, you'll see they are there for a reason.

Comment: @Drkawashima ...And `top: 50%` works because `float` changes the element's display type to a "block like" one, but if  one were to set that pseudo to `absolute`, then a parent would need a position other than `static` to control its position.

Comment: @Asons: maybe Chrome Devtools is misleading here but if I run the code snippet and inspect the element it'll list `top:50%` as ignored with the comment `The position: static property prevents top from having an effect.Try setting position to something other than static.`

Comment: @Drkawashima ...Sorry, my mistake, you're right about that, I tested with some different settings and missed I had a class with another position set for that element.

Comment: @Drkawashima : Thanks for your note, updated my answer, added some more info and a second solution.